# Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

Today i got into situation where my android studio unable to build the project. It say's 
Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the

I have Android Studio 2.1
The problem is with only one project, other projects are working fine. I thought it was due to svn, so i turn off the svn for this project but still not able to build the project. Any help is really appreciated.